# R data.table list output vs vector output

Tags: r, list, data.table, grouping, aggregation

```
d <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Aira", "Ben", "Cat"), class = "factor"), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Rate1 = c(12L, 18L, 19L, 53L, 22L, 19L, 22L, 67L, 45L), Rate2 = c(23L, 73L, 45L, 19L, 87L, 45L, 87L, 43L, 32L)), .Names = c("Name", "Month", "Rate1", "Rate2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L)) 

> d
   Name Month Rate1 Rate2
1: Aira     1    12    23
2: Aira     2    18    73
3: Aira     3    19    45
4:  Ben     1    53    19
5:  Ben     2    22    87
6:  Ben     3    19    45
7:  Cat     1    22    87
8:  Cat     2    67    43
9:  Cat     3    45    32
```

I have the above data.table and want to know the difference between the following two operations. I know `.()` is short for `list` and `c()` is a vector. What does `data.table` do with these two different syntax? All I can observe is that the first case resulted in two variables and the second case resulted in a single variable.

```
> d[, .(mean(Rate1), mean(Rate2)), by = Name]
   Name    V1    V2
1: Aira 16.33 47.00
2:  Ben 31.33 50.33
3:  Cat 44.67 54.00
```

and

```
> d[, c(mean(Rate1), mean(Rate2)), by = Name]
   Name    V1
1: Aira 16.33
2: Aira 47.00
3:  Ben 31.33
4:  Ben 50.33
5:  Cat 44.67
6:  Cat 54.00
```

Comment: I'm still learning `data.table`, but I had never thought to use `c(...)`. Interesting to see that a summarizing function would return more than one row per group, I can see that as very useful in some circumstances. I'm not certain where your question is, though: your code is good at demonstrating the difference: in the `.(...)` case you get one row per group. I suspect the equivalent of your second command is `d[, .(c(mean(Rate1), mean(Rate2))), by = Name]`, which might clear up why it returns a single column, each group with two rows.

Comment: Please have a look at the nice vignette [Introduction to `data.table`](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html): "As long as `j` returns a list, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting `data.table`"; "When there’s only one column or expression to refer to in `j` [...], we can drop the `.()` notation. This is purely for convenience." In your case, the `c()` concatenates the two means to _one_ column.

Comment: @r2evans - I suppose `j` + `by=` are not strictly a summarizing function, but rather a flexible grouping capability. You can even return more rows than are in the original data.

Comment: Yes, @thelatemail, I'm gathering that. This is one key difference between `data.table` summarizing and `dplyr::summarize`, where it fails if the returned summary is other than length 1. In `dplyr`-land, I would have summarized with a `do(...)` block so that I can return more than 1, it's nice to not have to do something similar here.